# Yii CDbConnection cache not working

Tags: php, caching, yii

I am having an issue getting a specific query to cache properly.  Caching is working in other places in my app,  so I think I have everything configured properly,  but I cannot get this specific instance to work.

My config

```
'cache'=>array(
    'class'=>'system.caching.CFileCache',
    ),
```

Then,  the code I am trying to execute:

```
static public function getCities()
{

    Yii::trace("Getting unique set of cities");
    $sqlStatement = "select distinct city from mls_data where city <> '' order by city";
    $connection = Yii::app()->db;
    $connection->cache(18000);

    $command= $connection->createCommand($sqlStatement);

    // execute an SQL query and fetch the result set
    $reader=$command->query();

    // each $row is an array representing a row of data
    foreach($reader as $row)
    {
        $returnArray[$row["city"]] = ucwords ( strtolower( substr($row["city"],0,17)));
    }

    return $returnArray;

}
```

The sql is executed property,  and returns as expected,  it just never creates a cache entry and then never pulls from the cache.

Anyone see anything I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
$connection = $connection->cache(18000);
```

Comment: Tried that,  no change.  According to the documentation cache should set the property and then simply returns an instance of itself,  so either way should technically work.

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the cache in the query line like this:

```
$result = $command->cache(18000)->query();
```